# Starting php-cgi: spawn-fcgi: child signaled: 25

Tags: centos, php-cgi

```
Starting php-cgi: spawn-fcgi: child signaled: 25
```

Does anybody know what this could mean? I'm trying to start php-cgi on CentOS.

The only thing I can say is that it was working before the hosting shut the server down for maintenance. I don't know if it's important, but `nmap -v -sV localhost -p 9000` shows: `9000/tcp closed cslistener`. Port 9000 should be open, right? Sorry to be so vague, I know almost nothing about this stuff. If you need more info, please ask in comments.

**Edit:** output of `ulimit -a`:

```
core file size          (blocks, -c) 0
data seg size           (kbytes, -d) unlimited
scheduling priority             (-e) 0
file size               (blocks, -f) unlimited
pending signals                 (-i) 32512
max locked memory       (kbytes, -l) 32
max memory size         (kbytes, -m) unlimited
open files                      (-n) 1024
pipe size            (512 bytes, -p) 8
POSIX message queues     (bytes, -q) 819200
real-time priority              (-r) 0
stack size              (kbytes, -s) 10240
cpu time               (seconds, -t) unlimited
max user processes              (-u) 32512
virtual memory          (kbytes, -v) unlimited
file locks                      (-x) unlimited
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to `man 7 signal`, on x86 hardware signal 25 is `SIGXFSZ` "File size limit exceeded".

Update your question with the output of `ulimit -a` (from whatever shell you're trying to start php-fpm from)

Comment: I addded the output of `ulimit -a`.

Comment: @p2ph8 ok, it's not a `ulimit` problem.  Can you check your log files and make sure they haven't grown too large? (2GB is the maximum file size for any 32-bit program without largefile support)

Comment: that was it man! The error log was 2GB. Thanks!